# Typescript: bind function no overload matches this call

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```js
type FormState = "email" | "password" | "whatever";

const f = <
  T extends FormState,
  K extends keyof T
>(
  fieldName: K,
  fieldValue: T[K],
  hasErrors?: boolean
) => {}

f.bind(null, "email"); // <-- This gives error
```

I'm unable to change neither the type nor the function, how can I use bind here?

This is a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYGVgENjQLxQEQRLoCWANnlAD75joDOdA7ogCYXV6MAWmEAbhAR4A3AChRAYzgA7OsCgAzKLgA8AFSgQAHlmks6sRKgxYANFADSmnRD0GA1hBBwlagHwAKBcQikWAOXQkCAAuS3NvXxYANXRSAFdQqDUAbQsAXXMeOgBRBAREOgB+MIAjODhSCHRpAEplNygAbwBfcQUAOlLiPQ9peNJScwIiMjxa4SA) to the typescript playground.

The log of the error is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 6, '(this: (this: null, arg0: number | ... 42 more ... | "padEnd", fieldValue: string | ... 42 more ... | ((maxLength: number, fillString?: string | undefined) => string), hasErrors?: boolean | undefined) => void, thisArg: null, arg0: number | typeof iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | ... 31 more ... | "padEnd"): (fieldValue: string | ... 42 more ... | ((maxLength: number, fillString?: string | undefined) => string), hasErrors?: boolean | undefined) => void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"email"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | unique symbol | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | ... 28 more ... | "padEnd"'.
  Overload 2 of 6, '(this: (this: null, ...args: "email"[]) => void, thisArg: null, ...args: "email"[]): (...args: "email"[]) => void', gave the following error.
    The 'this' context of type '<T extends FormState, K extends keyof T>(fieldName: K, fieldValue: T[K], hasErrors?: boolean | undefined) => void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: null, ...args: "email"[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'fieldName' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type '"email"' is not assignable to type 'number | unique symbol | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | ... 28 more ... | "padEnd"'.
```

Answer (score 1):

`K extends keyof T` and `T extends FormState` mean `K` will get `0`, `1`, or `2` ... as value.

Then your `f` function will look like this:

```
const f = (fieldName: number, fieldValue: string, hasErrors?: boolean) => {}

// and to bind f you have to bind a number as the second parameter
f.bind(null, 0);
```

But, I guess it is not what you want, I think you need the `fieldName` is `FormState`. Just try to update the type of `fieldName` to `T` instead of `K`

```
const f = <T extends FormState, K extends keyof T>(fieldName: T, fieldValue: T[K], hasErrors?: boolean) => {}

f.bind(null, "email");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong types because you are doing `keyof FormState` is the same as doing `keyof string` which just gives you the string methods.  Perhaps you should limit your function to a single parameter or enhance your types?

```
type FormState = "email" | "password" | "whatever";

const f = <T extends FormState>(fieldName: T, hasErrors?: boolean) => {}
f.bind(null, "email");
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYGVgENjQLxQEQRLoCWANnlAD75joDOdA7ogCYXV6MAWmEAbhAR4A3AChRAYzgA7OsCgAzKLgA8AFSgQAHlmks6sRKgxYAfAAoFxCKRYA5dEggAuKGoA0UHnQCiCBIh0APyuAEZwcKQQ6NIAlMqmUADeAL6iCgB0ocR65tIArqSkngREZHixwkA)